# How to hide light object keeping the Light effect?

Tags: 3d-view, light, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I use EEVEE preview my animation scene.I want to animate in this state.
The LightShape displayed in the scene affected my observation of the animation.
I want hide these light shapes.but The scene lost its light effect.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable light objects visibility from the *Overlays* popover.

[image]